# Case insensitive OSX file system - weird change directory (cd) bash behaviour

Tags: bash, macos

From what I know the default OSX file system is case insensitive.
Actually from terminal I can type either:

```
echo foo
```

or

```
ECHO foo
```

But with the `change directory` command I can only do:

```
cd /etc
```

Nothing appens if I type

```
CD /etc
```

Can anyone explain me please?

Comment: If `CD` is hashed, then it should work!

Comment: Check `type cd` and `type CD` output.

Comment: Does it work on your mac?

Comment: The `type CD` output is `CD is hashed (/usr/bin/CD)`, the `type cd` output is `cd is a shell builtin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directory change only works for the duration of the program which calls corresponding system call. You indicate in the comments that `CD` is `/usr/bin/CD` (as `type CD` said), which is a (quite useless for your objective) program: it'll change the directory and then quit, without affecting the parent program. At the same time, `cd` should be a bash builtin. This makes it possible for bash to retain the path `cd` changes into after the command quits.

See also: [What is the point of the `cd` external command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/27672) on Unix&Linux StackExchange.

Comment: Ok, you're telling me that case insensitive command behaviour for builtin commands works only because for each built in function exists a program with the same name in the path (ex. builtin echo and /bin/ECHO). For `change directory(cd)` the command can't be equivalent to the builtin.

Comment: @Luca right. And you can observe this in the first place because despite filesystem of macOS being case-insensitive, bash is still case-sensitive.

Comment: @Luca:  just because file names are not case sensitive does not mean that commands in any programming language (which `bash` is) are the same.  Mac OS is unusual in the UNIX-like world in having a case-insensitive default filesystem.

Comment: Not *every* built-in has a corresponding external program. Originally, shells were very minimal programs for running external programs and little else. Over time, shells began providing built-in versions of commands like `echo` for efficiency. `cd`  is primarily useful only if it is built-in, but [there are some reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command) to have an external command as well.